# How to write a regex for the following use case

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text.

```
<!-- FEO DEBUG OUTPUT [TextTransAttempted:RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(9), RENAME_IMAGE(59), MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(10), (1), EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(2), RENAME_CSS(3), (1), IMAGE_COMPRESSION(59);TextTransApplied:RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(9), RENAME_IMAGE(59), MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(10), (1), EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(2), RENAME_CSS(3), (1), IMAGE_COMPRESSION(59);TagTransAttempted:(73);TagTransApplied:(73); ] -->
```

I need to get the tag as well as the numbers out. This I have down in Python as follows.

```
tag_list = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z\d]+)+\(\d+\)', str(feed))
        for tag in tag_list:
            index = tag.index('(')
            result[tag[:index]] = int(tag.split("(")[1].rstrip(")"))
        print result
```

This prints the output as:-

`{'RENAME_CSS': 3, 'IMAGE_COMPRESSION': 59, 'MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT': 10, 'RENAME_JAVASCRIPT': 9, 'RENAME_IMAGE': 59, 'EMBED_JAVASCRIPT': 2}`

Now I want to do this only for the applied on in the above text. For instance I want to get the above info only for 'TextTransApplie' or 'TagTransApplied' .

I tried the following :-

`re.findall(r'TextTransApplied:[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z\d]+)+\(\d+\)` but this gives only the first value. How do I get the entire values for all the applied ones.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: The expected output would be a dictionary as above but the data needs to processed from the applied section. Like from TextTransApplied or TagTransApplied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting all the content inside the capturing group and then process the string.
(I've slightly modified your existing logic and I have changed the `RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(9)` to `RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(19)` just to illustrate the difference)

```
import re
s = '<!-- FEO DEBUG OUTPUT [TextTransAttempted:RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(19), RENAME_IMAGE(59), MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(10), (1), EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(2), RENAME_CSS(3), (1), IMAGE_COMPRESSION(59);TextTransApplied:RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(9), RENAME_IMAGE(59), MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(10), (1), EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(2), RENAME_CSS(3), (1), IMAGE_COMPRESSION(59);TagTransAttempted:(73);TagTransApplied:(73); ] -->'
tag_list = re.findall(r'(?:TextTransAttempted|TextTransApplied):\s*((?:(?:[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z\d]+)+)?\(\d+\)\s*(?:,\s*|;))*)', s)
for tag in tag_list:
    result = {}
    for e in tag.split(","):
        index = e.index('(')
        if e[:index].strip():
            result[e[:index].strip()] = (e.split("(")[1].rstrip(");"))
    print result


'''
OUTPUT
>>> 
{'RENAME_CSS': '3', 'IMAGE_COMPRESSION': '59', 'MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT': '10', 'RENAME_JAVASCRIPT': '19', 'RENAME_IMAGE': '59', 'EMBED_JAVASCRIPT': '2'}
{'RENAME_CSS': '3', 'IMAGE_COMPRESSION': '59', 'MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT': '10', 'RENAME_JAVASCRIPT': '9', 'RENAME_IMAGE': '59', 'EMBED_JAVASCRIPT': '2'}
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to get everything that pertains to `TagTransApplied`/`TextTransApplied` first, then pull out the parts you need:

```
import re

feed = """<!-- FEO DEBUG OUTPUT [TextTransAttempted:RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(9), RENAME_IMAGE(59), MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(10), (1), EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(2), RENAME_CSS(3), (1), IMAGE_COMPRESSION(59);TextTransApplied:RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(9), RENAME_IMAGE(59), MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(10), (1), EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(2), RENAME_CSS(3), (1), IMAGE_COMPRESSION(59);TagTransAttempted:(73);TagTransApplied:(73); ] -->"""

result = dict()
tagged = re.findall(r'T(?:ag|ext)TransApplied[^;]+', str(feed))
for part in tagged:
    tag_list = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z\d]+)+\(\d+\)', part)
    for tag in tag_list:
        id = tag.index('(')
        result[tag[:id]] = int(tag.split("(")[1].rstrip(")"))
print result
```

Result:

```
{'RENAME_CSS': 3, 'IMAGE_COMPRESSION': 59, 'MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT': 10, 'RENAME_JAVASCRIPT': 9, 'RENAME_IMAGE': 59, 'EMBED_JAVASCRIPT': 2}
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/DtdPgq)